# How to prevent MDI child form changing when input arrow keys?

Tags: c#, .net, forms, winforms, mdi

**What I implement**

- My application hold mdi child forms(don't close) when user opens other child to keep last input data.
- Child forms are shown as Maximized.

**What I want to stop**

- When user input arrow keys after over two child forms were opened(I think it's when child form focused), child forms are navigated(Up/Left : prev child open, Down/Right : next child) and shown as Maximized property is released(some case didn't).

I have searched for long time, there are some solutions about capturing keys but any solutions for stop this.

Please help me.

**+ conditions to reproduce this problem**

- MDI parent has ToolStripPanel & ToolStrip docking at the right
- parent also have MenuStrip(Visible property set to false) docking at the top to hide child form's control box
- ToolStripButton's Click Event Handler show child form using spaghetti function like next

```cs
private void tsbChildForm1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;                    
    if (m_frmChild != null)                                 
    {
        if (typeof(Form1) != this.ActiveMdiChild.GetType()) 
        {
            m_frmChild = new Form1();                       
            OpenChildForm(m_frmChild);                      
        }
        else
        {
            // do nothing. prevent memory increase
        }
    }
    else
    {
        m_frmChild = new Form1();                           
        OpenChildForm(m_frmChild);                          
    }
}

private void OpenChildForm(Form frmChild)
{
    if (LoadExistForm(frmChild))
    {
        // do nothing.
    }
    else
    {
        frmChild.MdiParent = this;
        frmChild.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        frmChild.Show();
    }
}

private bool LoadExistForm(Form frmChild)
{
    foreach (Form frmEach in this.MdiChildren)
    {
        if (frmEach.Name.Equals(frmChild.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            frmEach.Select();
            frmEach.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            frmChild.Dispose();
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

1. Load MDIParent
   [image]
2. Click each ToolStripButton and Load Child Form
   [image]
3. Push 'Up' arrow key just one time
   [image]

Comment: Do you want to build this navigation or do you have it and want to stop it ?

Comment: @GuidoG I have and want to stop it

Comment: I dont have this in my mdi application.  Can you describe what I need to do in my mdi application to reproduce the problem

Comment: @GuidoG I upload pictures and sample code.

Comment: plz someone edit grammatical errors

Comment: your problem has nothing to do with mdi but with this sidebar you are using. If it has focus than clicking an arrow button will move the the next/prior item on that sidebar. Why do you have this sidebar ?

Comment: @GuidoG I use sidebar(ToolStripPanel&ToolStrip) because It is best way  that I know to provide menu. Thanks for your opinion, but I don't think so. It is sure that my problem has to do with MDI, since It is repeated when I use buttons(System.Windows.Forms.Button) except sidebar. Above all things, *_Click event handlers which are showing child forms were never called when I clicked keyboard's arrow keys. I think that means child form was focused, not sidebar and clicking arrow key is cause focus changing among the child forms but not among the items on sidebar which have click event handler.

Comment: I have lots of mdi applications and never had this problem, so that is why i think it has to to with this sidebar. Why not use a normal menu instead of sidebar ?

Comment: @GuidoG Because, this form is familiar to my client...

Comment: @GuidoG And I wonder could you reproduce this problem. Is it apply just to me?

Comment: No I cannot reproduce the problem and I have many mdi applications. That is why i was guessing the sidebar has something to do with the problem. Can you disable the sidebar and see if the problem still occurs ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136328/discussion-between-tony-jang-and-guidog).

Comment: I have this problem and I did not know what was happening, I could not find anything anywhere, I was about to open a thread with my problem. My problem was that all the forms children were maximized and I thought that pressing the arrow keys would close the forms. The solution below corrected the problem. I was very lucky to find this thread.

Answer (score 1):

Add `PreviewKeyDown` event handler to your MDI Child form. It can filter keys you want your child form to handle.

```
private void Form_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.KeyCode)
    {
        case Keys.Up:
        case Keys.Down:
        case Keys.Left:
        case Keys.Right:
            e.IsInputKey = true;
            break;
    }
}
```